# Initialize a std::ofstream in a class using initializer list

Tags: c++, ofstream, initializer-list

I want to initialize a private `std::ofstream` (say, to a file opened in `main`) in a constructor using an initializer list. I have the following code:

```
class MyClass{
    std::ofstream ofs;
public:
    MyClass(const std::ofstream &ofs): ofs(ofs) { }
};
```

and I get the following compile error:

```
error C2248: 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
      ]
      c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\fstream(1034) : see declaration of 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream'
      with
      [
          _Elem=char,
          _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
      ]
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream)

```
basic_ofstream( const basic_ofstream& rhs) = delete;    (5)     (since C++11)
```

It is not possible to copy construct a `basic_ofstream`.

Possibly you are using pre-c++11 compiler and it is marked as `private` in the library.

Comment: Ah, I forgot it was trying to copy-construct. To achieve my purpose I just need to declare ofs as a reference. Thanks!